# Angular's form $dirty and input $dirty — Clarification?

Tags: angularjs

I've read [**here**](http://www.ng-vinod.com/2014/07/angularjs-pristine-dirty-valid-invalid.html) about form validation in NG.

So , I have a `form` :

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>
```

And an `input` :

```
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
```

And a `span` for errors :

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
```

It is working as expected ( when there is no data):

[image]

And I do see the change in CSS classes :

```
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required="" class="ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

**Question**

**But** according to the [article](http://www.ng-vinod.com/2014/07/angularjs-pristine-dirty-valid-invalid.html) I *can ALSO use* it :

- In Form: `myForm.$dirty`
- For Field:`myForm.user.$dirty`

So why does both `myForm.$dirty` and  `myForm.user.$dirty` yields `undefined` in console ?

[**Full JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/yekufe/1/edit?html,output)

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are treating `myForm` as global in console. Put this within your view: `<pre>{{myForm|json}}</pre>` will see they are defined but only within that scope

Comment: @charlietfl I do see the json. but can't I test values in console ? or is it only available to the ng's scope

Comment: form `name` becomes scope variable also in controller ... `$scope.myForm`

Comment: @charlietfl I know. I'm asking about the `$dirty` prop. So I guess that $dirty is only visible to the **ng's scope variable** of the form and input...?right ?

Comment: not totally correct...is available within applicable angular scope. This is no different than anything else regarding angular scoping

Comment: @charlietfl So why [I don't see it](http://i.imgur.com/zErTlIN.png) in [here](http://jsbin.com/yekufe/3/edit?html,output) ?

Comment: because `this` is the controller itself, not the element.

Comment: Hint: I recommend using ngMessages which is way more cleaner than having to do ng-show stuff. See this nice article here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html